# How to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} ( \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!} \prod_{l=0}^{k-1} (1 - \frac{l}{n}) )$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \Big( \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!} \prod_{l=0}^{k-1} (1 - \frac{l}{n}) \Big)$. I already know the limit should be $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}$, but I can't formally justify it.

A series is defined as the limit of the partial sums. But here we have a partial sum which is dependent on $k$ and $n$. I haven't seen that before and this confuses me. What is the correct way of evaluating such a limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed $z \in \mathbb{C}$, define$$
a_n(k) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac{z^k}{k!} \prod_{l = 0}^{k - 1} \left(1 - \frac{l}{n}\right); & k \in \mathbb{N},\ 0 \leqslant k \leqslant n\\
0; & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$
Since for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$,$$
|a_n(k)| = 0 \leqslant \frac{|z|^k}{k!} \ \text{or}\ |a_n(k)| \leqslant \frac{|z|^k}{k!} \prod_{l = 0}^{k - 1} \left(1 - \frac{l}{n}\right) \leqslant \frac{|z|^k}{k!},
$$
and $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{|z|^k}{k!} = \mathbb{e}^{|z|} < +\infty$, by the dominated convergence theorem,\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!} \prod_{l = 0}^{k - 1} \left(1 - \frac{l}{n}\right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_n(k) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n(k)\\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{z^k}{k!} \prod_{l = 0}^{k - 1} \left(1 - \frac{l}{n}\right) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}.
\end{align*}

Comment: So the essence is, because $|z|^k / k!$ is convergent, therefore $|a_n(k)|$ is too and I can take the limit inside and it becomes $\lim |z|^k / k! \cdot \lim \prod (\ldots)$ ?

Comment: Yes, and this is the discrete version of the dominated convergence theorem.